# Node js slow performance on 60 connections

Tags: performance, node.js, mobile, connection

I'm using NodeJS to put flag in memcache.

This is code:

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var memcache = require('memcache');

var client = new memcache.Client();

server.listen(3005);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('connected');
    
    socket.on('check',function(data){
    
        client.on('connect', function(){
           console.log('connect');
        });

        client.connect();
        
        client.set(data.id, 1, function(error, result){
    
            console.log('Key added');
            console.log(result);
            
            client.get(data.id, function(error, result){

                socket.emit('checked',data.id);

            });
        },600);
    });
});
```

In same time I have about 60 connections.

Some users complain that this code takes about 10-12 seconds to load.

Added `socket.disconect()` after `socket.emit('checked',data.id)` but it start to work slower.

Any ideas?

### UPDATE

All users use Android / iOS native browsers.

Comment: For those lagging users was network/browser a problem. If their transport method is long-polling, this delay could be due to that, specially on unsupported browsers. Try logging all incoming connections' transport to check this. Also is there more to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't connect to memcached on each call, instead reuse an existing connection:

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var memcache = require('memcache');

var client = new memcache.Client();

server.listen(3005);

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connect');

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.emit('connected');

        socket.on('check',function(data){
            client.set(data.id, 1, function(error, result){

                console.log('Key added');
                console.log(result);

                // maybe unnecessary, just check if error is present
                client.get(data.id, function(error, result){
                    socket.emit('checked',data.id);
                });
            },600);
        });
    });
});

client.connect();
```

Comment: Interesting idea, many connections can kill server. Will try and let know result.

Comment: Can't now test it in live, but this answer worth the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

You call:

```
client.connect();
```

but your corresponding connection handler merely logs a message rather than performing the action you wanted to perform.

```
client.on('connect', function(){
  console.log('connect');
});
```

You have a function:

```
client.set(data.id, 1, function(error, result){
  console.log('Key added');
  console.log(result);
  client.get(data.id, function(error, result){
    socket.emit('checked',data.id);
  });
},600);
```

.. which really should be wrapped inside the `client.on("connect")` handler so I wonder why your code succeeds at all?

Possibly your first or first few attempts to access memcached fail but then succeed because the `client` variable is re-used and the connection may stay alive. But - risky.

Comment: Didn't notice that. Thanks. But is that a main problem of performance? I forgot to write, all users use Android/iOS native browsers.

Comment: After connection (to socket.io, not to memcached) code works fast, but it takes lot of time to load socetio.js and connection.